# Next PWA not build error in Turbo monorepo, but not as an individual folder

Tags: typescript, next.js, progressive-web-apps, turborepo, next-pwa

I was trying to deploy a turborepo PWA. It works perfectly in development however on building the files I get this error
I am using

- Next.js 13.4.4
- turbo 1.9.7
- next-pwa 5.6.0

```
pwa-experimental:build: - info Generating static pages (3/4)
pwa-experimental:build: - info Generating static pages (4/4)
pwa-experimental:build: 
pwa-experimental:build: > Export encountered errors on following paths:
pwa-experimental:build:         /_error: /404
pwa-experimental:build:         /_error: /500
pwa-experimental:build:         /test-pages
pwa-experimental:build: error Command failed with exit code 1.
pwa-experimental:build: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
pwa-experimental:build: ERROR: command finished with error: command (/home/siddarth/Desktop/Vivly-monorepo/vivly/apps/--experimental-pwa) yarn run build exited (1)
command (/home/siddarth/Desktop/Vivly-monorepo/vivly/apps/--experimental-pwa) yarn run build exited (1)

 Tasks:    0 successful, 2 total
Cached:    0 cached, 2 total
  Time:    7.468s 
Failed:    pwa-experimental#build

 ERROR  run failed: command  exited (1)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This does not happen if I try to build the file in an external folder with the same configurations , except for removing the local packages

My **Next.Config.js** is as follows

```js
const path = require("path");
const withPWAInit = require("next-pwa");

/** @type {import('next-pwa').PWAConfig} */
const withPWA = withPWAInit({
  dest: "public",
  // Solution: https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/issues/424#issuecomment-1399683017
  buildExcludes: ["app-build-manifest.json"],
});

const generateAppDirEntry = (entry) => {
  const packagePath = require.resolve('next-pwa');
  const packageDirectory = path.dirname(packagePath);
  const registerJs = path.join(packageDirectory, "register.js");

  return entry().then((entries) => {
    // Register SW on App directory, solution: https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/pull/427
    if (entries["main-app"] && !entries["main-app"].includes(registerJs)) {
      if (Array.isArray(entries["main-app"])) {
        entries["main-app"].unshift(registerJs);
      } else if (typeof entries["main-app"] === "string") {
        entries["main-app"] = [registerJs, entries["main-app"]];
      }
    }
    return entries;
  });
};

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    const entry = generateAppDirEntry(config.entry);
    config.entry = () => entry;

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = withPWA(nextConfig);
```

I have tried looking for a solution on github and stack.
The above errors occur due to some undefined context in the build files

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/test-pages". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

There seems to be some information about this error on github which I have tried to implement, however it doesn't work for me.
The custom next.config.js is for making next-pwa work with the app router, I am not sure if that would be causing the problem however
**I have not used context anywhere in the application if anyone was curious.**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.